# printdocument how to print large line complete?

Tags: c#, printing, streamwriter, printdocument

[image]

image says all, there is 3 lines which not appears complete then when i print they dont see complete.

is there a property for this print the line down until this  print all the complete line?

or the unique way is i count the letters by line and I do a WriteLine()?

this is a txt bulid in c#

> Cod Ope       Nombre      Error       Información adicional        39546  MICHEL ONTIVEROS
>   PABLO IGNACIO error   exec grabaped
>   10asdfdsfñljadñsklfjkadsjfjasdljfkñladsñlfjklajskldfjklñadskjlfañklsdjñklfkñladsñkjflklkñjadsHola
>   mundo, hola mundo 2, hola como estas, esta es una cadena muy larga
>   blablal etc whats  39547  BEBIDAS DE LOS ANGELES, S.A.    error   exec
>   39548 TAPON CORONA, S.A. DE C.V.      error   exec     42802  OPERADORA
>   Q-LOGISTICS           error   exec     852    Unilever de México S.A de C.V
>     error   exec     851    Concesionaria de Productos Jag  error   exec
>   881   Municipio de Merida Yucatan     error   exec     846    Chetumal Q.Roo
>     error   exec     40715  JUGOS DEL VALLE                 error   exec
>   847   CanCun Q.Roo (Playa del Carmen  error   exec     39547  BEBIDAS DE LOS
>   ANGELES, S.A.     error   exec grabaped
>   10asdfdsfñljadñsklfjkadsjfjasdljfkñladsñlfjklajskldfjklñadskjlfañklsdjñklfkñladsñkjflklkñjads 
>   39548 TAPON CORONA, S.A. DE C.V.      error   exec grabaped
>   10asdfdsfñljadñsklfjkadsjfjasdljfkñladsñlfjklajskldfjklñadskjlfañklsdjñklfkñladsñkjflklkñjads

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is not a property you can use. You can use the `Graphics.MeasureString()` method to check the length of your text against the width of your document. Also, take into account the print document's page margin - if you have set them. If your text is too long use the `String.Split()` method and write a new line.

Counting the letters is not a reliable way since some letters are wider than others depending on the font you use.

Comment: Stiger I get it, you could see in my self answer

Answer (score 0):

I get thing I wanted doing it

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            string ruta = @"..\wbcimpresion"+destino+".txt";
            //borra si existe
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(ruta))
                System.IO.File.Delete(ruta);
             //creo mi archivo

                if (kryptonDataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    System.IO.StreamWriter escritor = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ruta);


                    for (int columna = 0; columna < kryptonDataGridView1.Columns.Count; columna++)
                    {
                        escritor.Write(kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[columna].HeaderText.ToString()+"\t\t");
                    }


                    for (int fila = 0; fila < kryptonDataGridView1.Rows.Count; fila++)
                    {
                        escritor.WriteLine();
                        System.IO.StringWriter stringescritor = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                        for (int columna = 0; columna < kryptonDataGridView1.Columns.Count; columna++)
                        {


                            stringescritor.Write
                                (
                               kryptonDataGridView1.Rows [fila].Cells [columna ].Value.ToString ()+"\t"

                                );

                        }

                        string dato = stringescritor.ToString();

                        if (dato.Length > 120)
                        {
                            int contador1 = 0;
                            while (dato.Length > 120)
                            {
                                if (contador1 == 0)
                                    escritor.Write(dato.Substring(0, 120));
                                else
                                {
                                    escritor.WriteLine();
                                    escritor.Write(dato.Substring(0, 120));
                                }
                                dato = dato.Remove(0, 120);
                                contador1++;
                            }
                            escritor.WriteLine();
                            escritor.Write (dato.Substring (0,dato.Length ));


                        }
                        else
                        { 
                        escritor.Write (dato.Substring (0,dato.Length ));
                        }
                    }
                    escritor.Flush();
                    escritor.Close();
                    escritor.Dispose();
                }



            string imprimeme = "";
            System.IO.StreamReader lector = new System.IO.StreamReader (ruta);
            imprimeme = lector.ReadToEnd();

            lector.Close();
            lector.Dispose();
            float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            float rightMargin = e.MarginBounds.Right;
            leftMargin = 40;
            rightMargin = 60;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(imprimeme, new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular ), Brushes.Black, leftMargin, rightMargin);





        }
```